# FileNotFoundException with PowerMock + Drools + JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, drools, powermock

Have anyone used the "PowerMock + Drools + JBoss" combination?

When I run try to unit test drools rules using in JUnit tests (JUnit 4.10) I load the drl rule knolage kobtext:

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/mycompany/myproject/rooles.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
```

And it works fine. 
org.drools.io.impl.ClassPathResource contains 3 classloaders:

- java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader
- org.jboss.mx.loading.UnifiedClassLoader
- sun.misc.Launcher

But when I add

```
@RunWith(org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.class)
```

to the unit test org.drools.io.impl.ClassPathResource contains 2 classloaders:

- org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader
- sun.misc.Launcher

and the test fails with java.io.FileNotFoundException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 'com/mycompany/myproject/rooles.drl' cannot be opened because it does not exist 
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:638) 
at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:28)
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 'com/wiley/cms/jqa/service/lifecycle/lifecycle.drl' cannot be opened because it does not exist 
at org.drools.io.impl.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:128) 
at org.drools.io.impl.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:109) 
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:352) 
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:538)
...
```

Could anyone suggest how to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add @PowerMockIgnore("org.drools.*") annotation.